# Keras, how to feed an Embedding layer with a random sampling of a Softmax layer

Tags: keras, word-embedding

In the model I am constructing, I have the following layer:

```
y = layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(x)
```

And I want the next layer of this model to be an Embedding layer that "represent" the choice made by the Dense layer.

I.e, I want

1. to sample a choice from **y** (based on the probability "represented" by the values of the softmax)
2. to turn this choice into an **Embedding Layer** with vocabulary size 10.

Any idea how to do this ?

Regards

Comment: I saw you unaccepted my answer. Does it not work? Let me know.

Comment: Hello, I am sorry but I was asking for a Layer that samples randomly (with the probas represented by the softmax)

Answer (score 0):

#### Initial answer

Add a layer that takes the argmax of the output of the dense layer before feeding it into the embedding layer to propagate the most likely category label:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K

# generate some data
BATCH_SIZE,INPUT_DIM = (4,2)
x = tf.random.uniform([BATCH_SIZE,INPUT_DIM])

# model
NUM_CLASSES = 10
EMBEDDING_DIM = 10
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(NUM_CLASSES,activation='softmax')(x)
argmax = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: K.argmax(x,axis=-1))(dense)
emb = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(NUM_CLASSES,EMBEDDING_DIM)(argmax)
```

#### Updated answer

If you want to propagate a randomly sampled category label instead of the most likely category label, you can do so by using `tf.random.categorical`. Note that `tf.random.categorical` takes logits as inputs, so you don't need the softmax activation at the end of the dense layer.

```
NUM_CLASSES = 10
EMBEDDING_DIM = 10
logits = tf.keras.layers.Dense(NUM_CLASSES)(x)
sample = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda logits: tf.squeeze(tf.random.categorical(logits, 1)))(logits)
emb = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(NUM_CLASSES,EMBEDDING_DIM)(sample)
```